# How to extend <li> elements to the full width of the <ul> container while also controlling the height?

Tags: html, css

Most solutions I've seen on SO and other sites call for making the display a table:

```
ul {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
ul li {
  display: table-row;
}
```

However, when I try to set a max height on the `<ul>` container, the `height` is ignored. How can I have the `<li>` elements extend the full length of the `<ul>`, while also being able to set a height on the `<ul>`?

Comment: `max-height` will only apply when the total height of the child elements (`<li>`, in this case) exceeds what that value is. are you trying for `min-height` as well?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  By default, li elements (list-item) will be the same width as the ul element (block).  Changing the display types to table-row and table respectively has the same effect.

Comment: @cimmanon That's inaccurate. If you try it yourself, you will see that that's not the case (and also by the number of other people asking the same question). My question has the additional caveat of controlling the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that: (If I understand what you are after).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li {
  background-color: plum;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Care about Flexbox Browser Compatibility before to use it. Check the website [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for example

Comment: Adding just the `flex: 1` to the <li> element did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
nav {
  background-color:blue;
}

ul {
  height:50em;   //change to whatever
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

ul li {
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:33.333333%;  // divide by total li's, in this case, i have 3 li's
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8s2o7ra0/3/

Comment: What if I don't know the total number of li's ahead of time? They're going to be added dynamically.

Comment: You could use JS to count them and adjust the height property in code.